# Background color not filling sides of row/column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I added some rows and columns to a section on a page and there is now a blank strip where the background color isn't filled in. I have all the rows on the page inside a div with class `container-fluid`. I tried setting padding on the sides of the affected section (with class `about`) to 0, there is no margin applied on the side (which would prevent it from being filled with color), and I tried `width: 100%`--the white space is still there. Any ideas as to what the problem is?

Full code: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/pen/PaNjLW) (note: remove color from body in CSS to see the blank space in CodePen)

HTML of affected section:

```
        <section class="about" id="about">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <h2>About</h2>
            </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <img src="img/circle-portrait-small.png" class="portrait">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
              <p>..(Removed)..</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
```

CSS for the section:

```
.about {
  background-color: WhiteSmoke;
}

.about {
  padding: 3em 0;
}

.about p {
  text-align: left;
}

.about .row {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: what do you want to acheive Natalie.

Comment: Just the blank space filled in with background color of the rest of the section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the grid you have built is not aligned with bootstrap's gird layout conventions. You should put the `rows` directly in the `container-fluid`.

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <section class="row" id="hero">
    <div class="col"></div>
  </section>
  <section class="row" id="about">
    <div class="col"></div>
  </section>
  <section class="row" id="portfolio">
    <div class="col"></div>
  </section>
  <section class="row" id="contact">
    <div class="col"></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

`container-fluid`, by default, has `15px` padding left and right.

```css
.container-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

`row`, by default, has `-15px` margin left and right.

```css
.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

If  you put all rows directly inside the container-fluid, you won't have that issue.

Check your [code-pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VdaQZM?editors=1100). I have fixed the issue.

---

You do not need to use this.

```css
.about .row {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks--I guess when using Bootstrap there's no way to have a section with multiple rows?

Comment: @NatalieCardot  You can do so as long as you use the correct grid structure: `container-fluid` or `container` > `row` > `col-*(s)`  .

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap's .container-fluid styling is adding padding to this section.

You can override it like this:

```
body .container-fluid {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

A simpler solution which doesn't mess with the container-fluid style is to just add the same background color to your body that you added on each section so the gap isn't visible:

```
html body{ background-color: #f5f5f5; }
```

Here's an updated version of your pen

https://codepen.io/suth_a/pen/NzNvdM

Comment: This causes other issues (blank spaces, horizontal scroll), and if you scroll to the right there's still white space on the side of the section.

Comment: yeah it's probably not good to mess with bootstraps styling if you can avoid it. Check my updated pen, found a very simple solution, just adding background color to the body

Comment: Good interim fix, thanks! Still wondering what the cause of the blank space is though...

Comment: it's being caused by .container-fluid because you wrapped all your html within it. This isn't an interim/hack fix this is a good fix which I've used in many production sites